# Getting info from Enum type parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm trying to access properties of an arbitrary Enum from inside a generic Java class. In particular, I'd like to access the number of values in the Enum as well as the actual values themselves.

This (obviously silly) dummy code illustrates the intent:

```
public class Test <E extends Enum>{
    public enum TestEnum {
        FIRST, SECOND, THIRD
    }
    public Test() {
        System.out.println(E.values().length);   //error - won't compile
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<TestEnum> t = new Test<TestEnum>();
    }
}
```

There are some solutions to similar problems here on StackOverflow, but they require modifying the Enum. It's important here that the code work for *any* arbitrary Enum.

Is this even possible in Java?

Thank you in advance for any possible advice.

~Chris

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. `Enum` is a type, you're tying to use it like an instance with `E.values()` (ignoring that `Enum` doesn't even have that method)

Comment: @BrianRoach: Actually, the code does make sense, or at least it would if not using generics. The following compiles and runs just fine:

    public class Example {
        public enum ExampleEnum {
            THIS, CODE, WORKS
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(ExampleEnum.values().length);
        }
}

(Sorry, the formatting gets all screwed up here)

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Enums are kinda bizarre in Java when it comes to the `Enum` class vs. the `enum` keyword. You could actually set a field in your class as: `E myEnum = (E) Test.TestEnum.First;` then do  `myEnum.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().length;` and it'll work. But there's no way to do it from the type (`Enum`) itself except via reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection and the static values method the compiler automatically adds when it creates an enum.

```
public class Test {

    public enum TestEnum {
        FIRST, SECOND, THIRD
    }

    public Test(Class<? extends Enum> enumType) throws IllegalAccessException,
            InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        Enum[] values = (Enum[]) enumType.getDeclaredMethod("values").invoke(
            null);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
            NoSuchMethodException {
        Test t = new Test(Test.TestEnum.class);
    }
}


>> [FIRST, SECOND, THIRD]
```

Comment: you should just do `Enum[] values = enumType.getEnumConstants();`

Answer (score 0):

To access actual class of E at runtime, it should be explicity set at compile time.

Setting it as type parameter does not work, for java type erasure.
I've just compiled Test class, and run javap for it:

```
...
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class Test
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //call no-arg constructor "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1            // store object reference to local variable 't'
   8:   return
```

So, constructor knows nothing about TestEnum type parameter.

The best suitable solution is to pass class parameter to constructor as [@stampy88 wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14784823/2056178).